# Failed to insert record rc:1, msg=table students has no column named year in iOS sqlite

Tags: ios

Failed to insert record  rc:1, msg=table students has no column named 
year

i have newly insert a column year but it show me error

```
sqlite3* db = NULL;
int rc=0;
rc = sqlite3_open_v2([filePath cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], &db, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE, NULL);
if (SQLITE_OK != rc)
{
    sqlite3_close(db);
    NSLog(@"Failed to open db connection");
}
else
{
    char * query ="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS students ( id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name  TEXT, age INTEGER, marks INTEGER, year INTEGER )";
    char * errMsg;
    rc = sqlite3_exec(db, query,NULL,NULL,&errMsg);

    if(SQLITE_OK != rc)
    {
        NSLog(@"Failed to create table rc:%d, msg=%s",rc,errMsg);
    }

    sqlite3_close(db);
}

return rc;
```

Comment: What happens if you drop the table?  My guess is you already have a table `students` table without `year` in it.